# Popup boxes open all at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of pictures that when clicked, open a popup box with info about the selected picture, but all the popup boxes open at the same time.
To start, I have some

```
<ul class="cenas_top">
            <li>
                <div class="shape">
                    <a href="#ef" class="overlay round"></a>

                    <div class="details">
                        <span class="heading">Direção</span>
                        <hr />      
                        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                        <button id="myBtn">Mais</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bg"></div>

                    <div class="base">
                        <img src=" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <h3>Name</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="shape">
                    <a href="#fc" class="overlay round"></a>

                    <div class="details">
                        <span class="heading">Direção</span>
                        <hr />      
                        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                        <button id="myBtn">Mais</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bg"></div>

                    <div class="base">
                        <img src=" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <h3>Name</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Then, I have the boxes:

```
  <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content" id="ef">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content" id="fc">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <h2></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Finally, this is how the script looks:

```
<script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

What's missing here?

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine here's the working example:

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, some of which you haven't mentioned in the question but are obvious anyway:

1) All your modal content is within one div called "myModal". When the button is clicked, you make this div visible. Therefore, all the content within it will become visible. You need to only open the modal content which is applicable to the clicked button.

2) All your buttons have the same `id`. This is invalid HTML. Element IDs must be unique. As it stands, only your first button will ever respond to the click event. The others will be ignored because they are considered invalid elements.

3) You're only adding the close event to the first `span`. So again this won't work for any of the others.

Here's an example that works. Note the match-up between the `data-content` attribute of each button, and the id of the corresponding modal.

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="cenas_top">
        <li>
            <div class="shape">
                <a href="#ef" class="overlay round"></a>

                <div class="details">
                    <span class="heading">Direção</span>
                    <hr />      
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                    <button class="modal-button" data-content="ef">Mais</button>
                </div>

                <div class="bg"></div>

                <div class="base">
                    <img src=" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>  
            <h3>Name</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="shape">
                <a href="#fc" class="overlay round"></a>

                <div class="details">
                    <span class="heading">Direção</span>
                    <hr />      
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                    <button class="modal-button" data-content="fc">Mais</button>
                </div>

                <div class="bg"></div>

                <div class="base">
                    <img src=" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>  
            <h3>Name</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>

<!-- The Modals -->
    <div id="modal-ef" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h2></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>      

    <div id="modal-fc" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h2></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var showModal = function() {
  var modalID = this.getAttribute("data-content");
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal-' + modalID);
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

var hideModal = function() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}

//event listeners to show the modals
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', showModal, false);
}

//event listeners to close the modals
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', hideModal, false);
}
```